# Periodic Task in Grails

Tags: grails

I want to run a periodic task within a Grails application. Can anyone recommend a best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My recommendation would be the [Quartz Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/quartz), here's a summary of the plugin from the site:

> Quartz plugin allows your Grails
>   application to schedule jobs to be
>   executed using a specified interval or
>   cron expression. The underlying system
>   uses the Quartz Enterprise Job
>   Scheduler configured via Spring, but
>   is made simpler by the coding by
>   convention paradigm.

Comment: I've used Quartz on J2EE apps, but I'm new to Grails so I didn't know there was a plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this based on the core JDK libraries is via the TimerTask, that should allow you to setup a recurring event:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

There's a good IBM article here on using it for this purpose:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule.html

If you want something more complex in terms of control then look at Quartz or Enterprise Quartz.